# Visual-Block mode not working in Vim with C-v on WSL@Windows 10

Tags: vim, copy-paste, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-terminal

I use WSL Ubuntu and Vim inside the new Windows Terminal, but if I have to enter the **visual-block mode** with C-v, I can't since it acts as paste.

I am okay with rebinding it to something else but I don't happen to have found the command that I have to add to `.vimrc`, I think it has something to do with **inoremap**.

Any advice?

Answer (score 56):

`CTRL+v` is bound to paste in Windows Terminal by default. As of now, the only thing that's working is to disable that behaviour in the [`settings.json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/install#settings-json-file). You can do that by pressing `CTRL+SHIFT+,`.

From version 1.4

```
  "actions": [
    ...
    // { "command": {"action": "paste", ...}, "keys": "ctrl+v" }, <------ THIS LINE
```

Pre version 1.4

```
  "keybindings": [
    ...
    // { "command": "paste", "keys": "ctrl+v" }, <------ THIS LINE
```

After doing this, you can switch to visual block mode as usual and paste with `CTRL+SHIFT+v`.

I've found these issues on the project's GitHub about this problem:

https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/5790

https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/5641

Info about the keybindings/actions change: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/actions

> As of Windows Terminal version 1.4, the keybindings array has been renamed to actions inside the settings.json file. Support for the keybindings array still exists for backward compatibility, however the terminal will not automatically rename keybindings to actions inside your settings.json file.

Comment: This works like a charm, you do not even need to restart the terminal session

Comment: Nice, gonna give this a try a year from now when Visual Studio finishes opening.

Comment: @JamesM.Lay if you drop the "sual Studio" part im sure wait times will decrease ;)

Comment: The "Open JSON" menu entry is no longer there on that menu - at least on my WSL2 Ubuntu system.

Answer (score 7):

try `Ctrl-q` in VISUAL BLOCK mode.

Answer (score 5):

You can just change the default **"settings.json"**

Orignal :

```
{
    "command": 
    {
        "action": "copy",
        "singleLine": false
    },
    "keys": "ctrl+c" 
},
{
    "command": "paste",
    "keys": "ctrl+v"
},
```

Modified :

```
{
    "command": 
    {
        "action": "copy",
        "singleLine": false
    },
    "keys": "ctrl+shift+c"
},
{
    "command": "paste",
    "keys": "ctrl+shift+v"
},
```

Comment: works for me. If you do not want the `ctrl-c` and `Ctrl-v` behavior, you can also delete these two.

Comment: settings.json is in `%LocalAppData%\Packages\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState` by the way.

Answer (score 2):

ctrl+v is also important for ":g/pattern/norm".
You don't need to change settings.json in order to delete the "ctrl+v" binding, now you can also click on "Actions", scroll to the "paste" binding and delete it (shift+insert will still be available)